# Sorting Listbox Items by DateTime values

Tags: c#, date, sorting, datetime, listbox

Is there any easy way to sort listbox items by `DateTime` values?
In my `listbox1` I have items formatted like this: `"2013.01.08 19:29:52"` so it's just `someDateTimeValue.ToString()`

Comment: Did you tried anything so far? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting a list of items in a list box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667088/sorting-a-list-of-items-in-a-list-box)

Comment: I also marked it as duplicate, but with closer look, it is slightly different as it involves `DateTime`

Comment: If your `DateTime` format is yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:tt then default sorting(Array.Sort) will work. Otherwise you need to first parse it as DateTime, then do the sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have 2 ListBoxes you could do something like the following

```
ArrayList arList = new ArrayList(); 
foreach (object obj in listBox1.Items)
{
    arList.Add(obj);
} 
arList.Sort(); 
listBox2.Items.Clear();
foreach(object obj in arList)
{
    listBox2.Items.Add(obj); 
}
```

Comment: Do you think it is ethical to copies someone's answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3667107/447156

Comment: @Soner I think that you are assuming this is my answer I am not sure why you would come out and accuse someone of using an answer..

Comment: I could add an even more complex answer but I think for the OP that would be over Kill..

Comment: @DJKRAZE, I think you should read [is-it-okay-to-copy-paste-answers-from-other-questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78658/is-it-okay-to-copy-paste-answers-from-other-questions). There is nothing wrong in copy as long as credit is going where it should go

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<ListItem> myList = new List<ListItem>(ListBox1.Items.Cast<ListItem>());        
myList = myList.OrderByDescending(li => li.Value).ToList<ListItem>();
ListBox1.Items.Clear();
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(myList.ToArray<ListItem>());
```

Comment: Why convert the enumeration from `Cast` to a `List` when the only thing you're going to do with it is enumerate it with `OrderBy`?  Why construct it with the constructor instead of `ToList` (which you do later)?  Why do you convert the result of `OrderBy` into a `List` only to immediately convert it to an `Array`? Why are you supplying the generic parameters to `ToList` and `ToArray`?  (They will be implied.)  You can just use `var items = ListBox1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().OrderByDecending(li => li.Value).ToArray()` then clear/addRange.

Comment: @Servy Please would you either submit an answer or modify this one to correctly portray your thoughts?  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

try to sort a list of dates and after that put in the listbox.

```
dateList.Sort();
var items = new SelectList(dateList);
```