# How to Sort an ObservableCollection Binded from IsolatedStorage

Tags: windows-phone-7, sorting, binding, windows-phone-8, observablecollection

I am binding a collection of images that I retrieve from IsolatedStorage to my View, but I am having issues with changing the order in which images are displayed. There is a timestamp associated with each image, and I would like to be able to sort by either ascending or descending order. As of now the binding works, but when I attempt to change the sort order before binding to my listbox, nothing shows on the UI.

MainPage.xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="Recent" ItemsSource="{Binding Pictures}" Margin="8"
                     SelectionChanged="recent_SelectionChanged" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
                     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel> 
            </ListBox>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
// Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //This is working, but is not sorted
        //DataContext = PictureRepository.Instance;

        //Attempt at sorting before binding
        //from SettingsPage, if AscendingSort = True then sort ascending
        if (Settings.AscendingSort.Value)
        {
            //Give no errors, but does not display on UI
            DataContext = PictureRepository.Instance.Pictures.OrderBy(s => s.DateTaken);                
        }
        else
        {
            DataContext = PictureRepository.Instance.Pictures.OrderByDescending(s => s.DateTaken);
        }
    }
```

Not sure exactly what the issue is here? 
Note, when debugging, I can see that PictureRepository.Instance contains the images in which to display in the view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Sort a ListBox of Images by Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159869/how-to-sort-a-listbox-of-images-by-date)

Comment: How is this different than the question you already asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
    listItems = new ObservableCollection<YourType>(listItems.OrderBy(x => x.DateTaken));
```

Comment: I am wondering how to exactly apply this to my solution. Within `PictureRepository.Instance` lies the ObservableCollection named `Pictures` that is populated with the images from IsolatedStorage. So would my solution look sometihng like `listItems = new ObservableCollection<MyType>(PictureRepository.Instance.Pictures.OrderBy(x => x.DateTaken));` and then set `DataContext = listItems;`?

Comment: If Pictures is your ObservableCollection type then YES, so your code should be `PictureRepository.Instance.Pictures = new ObservableCollection<MyType>(PictureRepository.Instance.Pictures.OrderBy(x => x.DateTaken));`.

Comment: I did use your solution, however I had to bind the listItems ObservablecCollection to the ItemsSource of my listbox.