# Modify sorting algorithm to work with listboxes?

Tags: c#, sorting, names

So I'm trying to figure out to modify this integer sorting algorithm to work with data elements (file names) alphabetically in a listbox but have no idea how?

I understand how the sorting algorithm below works and can implement it using an integer array. However, for listBoxes I can't seem to find any relevant examples on the net.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    Random rand = new Random();
    int numOfIntegers = 1000;
    int[] array;

    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        array = new int[numOfIntegers]; 

    }


    // sort a vector of type int using exchange sort
    public void ExchangeSort(int[] array)
    {
        int pass, i, n = array.Length;
        int temp;
        // make n-1 passes through the data 
        for (pass = 0; pass < n - 1; pass++)
        {
            // locate least of array[pass] ... array[n - 1]  
            // at array[pass] 
            for (i = pass + 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (array[i] < array[pass])
                {
                    temp = array[pass];
                    array[pass] = array[i];
                    array[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExchangeSort(array);
        listBox.Items.Clear();
        foreach (int i in array)
        {
            listBox.Items.Add(i);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Done");

    }
```

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667088/sorting-a-list-of-items-in-a-list-box

Comment: well how does not work. Because this code is written correct

Comment: you want to sort numbers alphabetically??

Comment: No, the data elements in the listbox which are basically file names (strings).

Comment: So for example, I create a listbox and add the following elements into it:    listBox.Items.Add("Hello");
            listBox.Items.Add("Steve");
            listBox.Items.Add("John");
            listBox.Items.Add("John");

Comment: Why not just set the `ListBox.Sorted` property to `True` and let it do the work for you?

Comment: The `ListBox.Items` collection supports sorting natively. Simply add to the `SortDescriptions` property and you are done: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcollection.sortdescriptions.aspx

Comment: @KenWhite I believe he is using WPF not WinForms but in both frameworks, the controls will sort for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could try LINQ:

```
public void sort(int[] array)
{
    array = array.OrderByDescending (a => a).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to sort strings. To compare strings you could simply use the [`String.CompareTo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w.aspx) method or if you need more than simple comparison, the [`StringComparator` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.aspx) should do for most use cases.

If you choose to do it this way, the condition while sorting would be something like this:

```
if (array[i].CompareTo(array[pass]) < 0)
```

And the rest of the code would probably stay about the same, except of course changing the `int[]` to `String[]`.

Now, that being said, I would suggest using a [`List<String>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) and just skip doing this work by hand altogether. See [`List.Sort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx) for reference.

To be a bit more specific, here's an example based on your code of what I mean.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<String> items;

    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        items = new List<String>(); 
        // Fill your list with whatever items you need
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        items.Sort();
        listBox.Items.Clear();
        foreach (String str in items)
        {
            listBox.Items.Add(str);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Done");

    }
}
```

Comment: Changing the line `if (array[i] < array[pass])` to `if (array[i].CompareTo(array[pass]) < 0)` in the `ExchangeSort()` method, as well as replacing `int[]` with `String[]` in the appropriate places will solve your problem. Also you will need to change `int temp;` to `String temp;` in the sort method.

Comment: Thanks for that. It looks like I forgot to replace the int with string.