# C# Arrays and Lists

Tags: c#

I want to add the items from the list box into a string array

However, when I run the code I get a Null Reference Exception on the variable declaration. Any ideas?

List items;
        string[] array;

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        items = new List<String>();
        listBox.Items.Add("Kevin");
        listBox.Items.Add("James");
        listBox.Items.Add("John");
        listBox.Items.Add("Mathew");
        listBox.Items.Add("George");
```

Comment: Far easier to use C#'s rich data types. List, Dictionary and SortedList etc.

Comment: Are you passing a null array?

Comment: What method calls ExchangeSort()? did you try to debug the code ? according to your error the array input parameter is null thus it is not sent by the calling method.

Comment: How is the method being called? Looks like a null value is being passed in.

Comment: Also, why not just use `Array.Sort` or similar?

Comment: Please include the code that calls ExchangeSort

Comment: What's `ExchangeSort`? Seems like bubble sort.

Comment: And this question is totally nothing related to sorting!!!

Comment: This is for homework. It's taken me 2 days and I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: The most possible source of problem is the assignments to `array`.

Comment: @AbeMiessler Okay. I've added it to the original post.

Comment: Can a `LIST` be iterated as an `ARRAY` in JAVA?

Comment: how do you populate the array, what is its size? can i see the declaration also?

Comment: In you button click event (Button_Click_2) you pass array to ExchangeSort but array is not defined in this function. Where is it defined?

Comment: You asked this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869351/modify-sorting-algorithm-to-work-with-listboxes/15869652#15869652) just before. The answer is the same for this: you could use LINQ. Else this seems like homework...

Comment: @devilfish17 It is. I'm just trying to understand it when it comes to dealing with strings. Sorting it using integers I'm fine with but sorting the listbox with strings I'm having difficulty with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise the array, you have only declared it as a member of the class:

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    array = new string[listbox.Items.Count];

    ExchangeSort(array);
    listBox.Items.Clear();
    foreach (string i in array)
    {
        listBox.Items.Add(i);
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Done");

}
```

Comment: I get the error message: Error 1 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry, it's Count, not Length